# Tried to summon golem with the alter but didn't work

Tags: terraria

Please tell me how to summon him. Does it have be hard-mode?

Answer (score 2):

to summon the golem you must first kill plantera, to kill plantera you must first kill all 3 mechanical bosses, to kill the mechanical bosses you must first kill the wall of flesh and unlock hard mode.